# What is double exclamation mark in C#?

Tags: c#, function, syntax, method-signature, c#-11.0

From *https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Hashtable.cs,475*:

```
public virtual bool ContainsKey(object key!!)
```

It looks like two null-forgiving operators. Is there a document about it?

Comment: It appears 9 times in that `Hashtable.cs` - that wasn't done by accident / typo

Comment: Since `T?` is a long-established notation for nullable types, and `!` is the NOT operator, the logical syntax for a not-null constraint should be `object!? key`.  But no, they had to pick something more confusing.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

This is a null-parameter check syntax which was going to be introduced in C# 11. This proposal has [since been rolled back](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp-11-preview-updates/#remove-parameter-null-checking-from-c-11) following community feedback.

The proposal [is here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2145), and the PR doing a first roll-out to the runtime [is here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/64720).

The syntax:

```
public void Foo(string bar!!)
{
}
```

Is roughly equivalent to:

```
public void Foo(string bar)
{
    if (bar is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bar));
    }
}
```

... although the actual implementation uses a throw helper, something like:

```
public void Foo(string bar)
{
    <PrivateImplementationDetails>.ThrowIfNull(bar, "bar");
}

[CompilerGenerated]
internal sealed class <PrivateImplementationDetails>
{
    internal static void Throw(string paramName)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName);
    }

    internal static void ThrowIfNull(object argument, string paramName)
    {
        if (argument == null)
        {
            Throw(paramName);
        }
    }
}
```

[See on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAExAagD4AEBMBGAsAKHQGYACLEgYQIG8CT6zT0AWEgMQHsOAKdbABhLAIAJwCEYgJR0GtfAxIBfAoqA).

Methods containing `throw` statements are less likely to be inlined by the JIT, so using a throw helper makes it more likely that your method can be inlined, which might remove the null-check altogether! [See on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxBAzmAPgAQEwEYCwAUJgMwAEOZAwkQN5kONlFOYAsZAcgKYDuAFAHtgAK24BjBGUEBCGQEoWjWkqYNMuAJz95AblVkAvgYPsyAeQA2AEyGiJUwYsJMVLtQygAzMkLIBefzIYAFdLS2cPDwQACwAnQV5gvjIAQTiAcxCwbhgETjDLAFEAD3FuAAcEKEEYfhgIHMEvIXk9AyYOxg1tdvcGY37mIbMASRhLWG4rW2ExSWlI5S6GGdbdYaZBzpGOccmYbh4BOYdFgzcorj51zcZBwyA==).

Note that the use of `!!` is an implementation detail of your method: it just causes the compiler to insert code which you could have written yourself anyway. This means that moving from `throw` to `!!` (or vice versa) is not a breaking change.

---

There are a couple of places where `!!` will get the compiler to generate code which you can't (easily) write by hand, however.

One place where `!!` is particularly useful is in records with primary constructors. For example:

```
public record Person(string Name!!, int Age);
```

In order to correctly null-check the `Name` parameter in previous versions of C#, you have to write this out longhand:

```
public record Person
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public int Age { get; init; }
    
    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        if (name is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        (Name, Age) = (name, age);
    }
    
    public void Deconstruct(out string name, out int age) =>
        (name, age) = (Name, Age);
}
```

Another place where `!!` does something which you can't write yourself is in chained constructor calls:

```
public class C
{
    public C(int i) { }
    public C(string s!!) : this(s.Length) { }
}
```

This null-checks `s` before accessing `s.Length`, something like this (which isn't valid C#):

```
public C(string s)
{
    if (s is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s));
    C(s.Length);
}
```

[See on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoBBmABM3AYUwG9NcL89CAKWAF1ygEpcTcBfcynImhFAAZcAZwCEY1iFz0AFlBE0RAOgAyAUxgBzOa3ZcMHIA=).

Another interesting aspect is that the null-checks are inserted before field assignments in constructors. For example:

```
public class C
{
    private readonly ExpensiveObject e = new ExpensiveObject();
    public C(string s!!) { }
}
```

Is compiled as:

```
public class C
{
    private readonly ExpensiveObject e;
    public C(string s)
    {
        if (s is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s));
        e = new ExpensiveObject();
    }
}
```

That is, the null-check happens before the instantiation of `ExpensiveObject`. [See on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQMwAIECYUGECwAoAb3xRJQAcAnKANwgBcBTFChiAEwHsYAbATxQCiADzIMYAZxoMA8sABWDAMZ0UTALwoYDAO6CRYydRnyldABQBKANzFSybGYQBGAAwpxAQg8WUBFAF98QLx8eww9UQkpWQVlXwCgA==).

Comment: The next logical steps are `string bar!!!`, where every assignment to this variable is followed by a corresponding autogenerated if-statement to check for null, and then `string bar!!!!` where every assignment is pre-checked if it would try to assign `null` to it, and then `string bar!!!!!` where even the values that are attempted assigned to the variable will generate a warning if there is a slight chance it could possibly, potentially, mayhaps, be `null`. Wonder what 6 exclamation marks would mean, I'm sure they'll think of something.

Answer (score 7):

According to the latest updates published by microsoft about c# 11, this feature seems to have been removed.

Source : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp-11-preview-updates/#remove-parameter-null-checking-from-c-11

> We previewed parameter null-checking as early as possible because we
> anticipated feedback. This feature allows !! on the end of a parameter
> name to provide parameter null checking before the method begins
> execution. We included this feature early in C# 11 to maximize
> feedback, which we gathered from GitHub comments, MVPs, social media,
> a conference audience, individual conversations with users, and the C#
> design team’s ongoing reflection. We received a wide range of feedback
> on this feature, and we appreciate all of it.
>
> The feedback and the wide range of insight we gained from this
> feedback led us to reconsider this as a C# 11 feature. We do not have
> sufficient confidence that this is the right feature design for C# and
> are removing it from C# 11. We may return to this area again at a
> later date.

Answer (score 2):

## The New C# 11 Parameter Null Checking Feature [`!!`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/64720)

The double exclamation mark `!!` is a **parameter null checking feature** that is replacing the following (older) null checking:

```
void Bar(object arg)
{
    if (arg is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arg));
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Hi");
    // use arg...
}
```

With this new way null check, the same code is much shorter:

```
void Bar(object arg!!)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hi");
    // use arg...
}
```

Both of these methods (and the next one) throws an [`ArgumentNullException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception?view=net-6.0) if the parameter is `null`

### Elaboration

Basically, using this code you are making sure that `object arg` is not `null`

### Another Way: [`ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(parameter)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception.throwifnull?view=net-6.0)

***edit:*** *this static method is introduced in C# 10 (.NET 6)* and is dependent on .NET 6 version

Simplified Code Example:

```
void Greeting(string name)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(name);
    Console.WriteLine($"Hi {name}");
}
```

With the latest PR instructions, this method can be used in places the `!!` is not possible:

> ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull is used where `!!` isn't possible, but the method call is

**The following PR page update states that `!!` for now can be used only in method arguments, although the C# language team is considering to add this operator to properties, locals and arbitrary expressions:**

> Note that !! is currently limited to only apply to method arguments,
> as that's the vast majority use case (as is exemplified by the changes
> made in this PR)

Expanded code example where `!!` is not available (for the variable we want to check for null):

```
void GetUserCities(string userId!!)
    {
        // suppose you got this data (that is inconsistent and may contain a null)
        // from an API request by the userId
        var cities = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
            {"UK", "London"},
            {"USA", "New York"},
            {"India", "New Delhi"},
            {"Wakanda", null},
        };
        foreach(var pair in cities) {
            try {
                ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(pair.Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Country: " + pair.Key + ", City:" + pair.Value);
            } catch(System.ArgumentNullException) {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not find a city for this country: " + pair.Key);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Country: UK, City:London
> Country: USA, City:New York
> Country: India, City:New Delhi
> Could not find a city for this country: Wakanda
> ```

Test this code [**here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dPpnLI)

Comment: I'm not sure that adding a new answer 6 days later helps much? Also `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull` is not dependent on the C# version, only the .NET version.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @canton7, any elaboration with references upon an existing answer and a hot topic is welcome because as more information we have as developers community, the better we grow. Also, About `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull`, it is dependent only on .NET version and I just made an edit to emphasize this, thank you.

Comment: I think the last code example is missleading as it is posted directly under the explanation  _With the latest PR instructions, this method is used in places the `!!` is not possible:_. But in this code fragment `!!` would be possible. I would suggest changing the example to one where `!!` is not possible.

Comment: Hi, @MarkusSafar I have added an example to your request.
The example is where !! is not possible, that is **inside the method**

Comment: I am not sure this example fits the purpose of the `!!` operator as you just show how to use `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull()`. You do not really show how `!!` is useful here.

Comment: @MarkusSafar this example shows the usage of  `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull()` this is why in this specific example I have integrated `!!` as a thought experiment for a must-have `userId` to call a pseudo API request to demonstrate the unavailability of `!!` inside a method.

Comment: Makes no sense to me as the example would compile and function just fine without `!!`, right? Or don't I see the point here?

Comment: The point is to give a live example to `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull()` the `!!` doesn't matter in this example. Although, to correct your point of view, the `!!` does affect the function in the following way: *if  the method is called with null `userId` you will have an `ArgumentNullException`*

Comment: That's the point. The question and your answer is about the `!!` operator. So your example should show exactly that and not something else. And I disagree with your statement (_if the method is called with null `userId` you will have an `ArgumentNullException`_) as `userId` is never used in your example.

Comment: @MarkusSafar this example requires imagination for the `!!` part (think it's there) because as I mentioned, it is written as pseudo because the point here is to explore and show another way to handle parameter null checking because it may benefit others

Comment: But don't you think you should also explain in an example how to make use of the `!!` operator properly? I don't see any example where it's use is required or is beneficial.