# Using null-forgiving for integer doesn't act like 'NotNull' in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, null, null-forgiving-operator

```
int? number1;//Nullable variable
int number2;//Not nullable variable

//After a while
number1 = 100;

number2 = number1! + 1;
//Compile error: Cannot convert source type 'System.Nullable<int>' to target type 'int'
```

I don't want to use `number1 ?? 0` etc. for not change my logic(consistency). (it can throw exceptions if `number1` is null, no problem)

Doesn't `!` means '*Trust me it is not null!*' ?

Why does C# not trust me in this case?

I know null-forgiving basics but why does the `!` operator not work here?

Why doesn't `number1!` act like `NotNull` in this case?

Comment: `int?` is fundamentally different from, say, `string?` because `int?` is really of type `Nullable<int>` while `string?` is still a `string` type, but it explicitly can be null. You have to use `number2 = number1.Value + 1` instead.

Comment: Try `!!` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71063730/what-is-double-exclamation-mark-in-c#:~:text=The%20double%20exclamation%20mark%20!!,nameof(arg))%3B%20%7D%20Console.

Comment: @KYL3R `!!` was a beta language feature to throw if a parameter is null, but it's since been removed from the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must get the `int` value out of the `int?` through the `Value` property because you need a `int` result here. You can still use the null-forgiving operator to access this property.

```cs
number2 = number1!.Value + 1;
```

Note that the null-forgiving operator is not doing a cast or conversion. It only tells the compiler: "I know what I am doing, this value is not null". This suppresses the compiler warning *"Nullable value type may be null."*

If you must test if the nullable int is not null, you can use pattern matching

```cs
if (number1 is int n) {
    number2 = n + 1;
}
```

or you can use the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) if using `0` instead of `null` is acceptable.

```cs
number2 = number1 ?? 0 + 1;
```

Here `number1 ?? 0` converts a `null` value into `0`. (This might have been what you thought the `!` did)

*Additional information*: If you are in a [nullable context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references), then the compiler checks whether a value can be null. If it thinks it can, e.g., because you have not tested `if(number1 is not null)`, then it issues the warning *"Nullable value type may be null."*. But you might be smarter than the compiler and know that your logic ensures the value not to be null. Then you would use the null-forgiving operator to tell the compiler that everything is okay. `!` only suppresses this warning. It does not influence what the code does. If you do not get the warning, then do not use the `!`. If you get the warning, either use the `!` or use my 2nd or 3rd solution or ensure that the number is not null with the null-coalescing assignment operator `number1 ??= 0;`

---

I would like to add that a nullable value type is very different from a nullable reference type.

- Value type: E.g. `int?` is a synonym for the struct `Nullable<int>`.
- Reference type: E.g. `string?` is the same type as `string` with a hint telling the compiler that we consider `null` to be a legal value.

Comment: is `!` required? what is the difference between `number1!.Value` and `number1.Value`?

Comment: See the additional information I have added to my response.

Comment: Congrats on 100K.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that the result of `number1! + 1;` is `int?` that cannot be assigned to `number2` declared as `int`. As said [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving), "The null-forgiving operator has no effect at run time. It only affects the compiler's static flow analysis", which means it does not know that your number1 is not null.